# Приложение работает не на всех версиях android. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api

Запускается приложение вроде как на всем версиях андройда до API 15, как собственно и указал в манифесте. Но вот есть одна проблема, когда нажимаю копку сканировать вайфай сети и выводить список всех доступных вокруг сетей, указывая всю информацию о этих сетях, на андройде 5.2 всё работает нормально, но вот, когда запускаю на 4.2, то выдаёт вот такую ошибку.
Вылетает вот такая ошибка:[image: Ошибка]

Возможно, я использую какую-нибудь функцию, которая не поддерживается API 17, но найти я её не могу. Мне через 3 дня отправлять проект на конкурс, но из-за этой ошибки я в полном бешенстве, уже прочесал весь интернет, примерно, четвёртый день не могу пофиксить данную проблему. Заранее спасибо =) Это мой первый проект на андройд, сильно тапками не кидайтесь. На всякий случай:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.admin.wifiscanner;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
        import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
        import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Element [] nets;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                detectWifi();
                Snackbar.make(view, "Сканирование...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void detectWifi() {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.startScan();
        List<ScanResult> wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();

        Log.d("TAG", wifiList.toString());

        this.nets = new Element[wifiList.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i< wifiList.size(); i++){
            String item = wifiList.get(i).toString();
            String[] vector_item = item.split(",");
            String item_essid = vector_item[0];
            String item_capabilities = vector_item[2];
            String item_level = vector_item[3];
            String ssid = item_essid.split(": ")[1];
            String security = item_capabilities.split(": ")[1];
            String level = item_level.split(":")[1];
            nets[i] = new Element(ssid, security, level);
        }

        AdapterElements adapterElements = new AdapterElements(this);
        ListView netList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listItem);
        netList.setAdapter(adapterElements);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class AdapterElements extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
        Activity context;

        AdapterElements(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.items, nets);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @NonNull
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null);

            TextView tvSsid = item.findViewById(R.id.tvSSID);
            tvSsid.setText(nets[position].getTitle());

            TextView tvSecurity = item.findViewById(R.id.tvSecurity);
            tvSecurity.setText(nets[position].getSecurity());

            TextView tvLevel = item.findViewById(R.id.tvLevel);
          //  String level = nets[position].getLevel();
            tvLevel.setText(nets[position].getLevel());
            return item;

          //  try{
          //      int i = Integer.parseInt(level);
          //    if (i>-50){
          //      tvLevel.setText("Высокий");
          //} else if (i<=-50 && i>-80){
          //     tvLevel.setText("Средний");
          //  } else if (i<=-80){
          //      tvLevel.setText("Низкий");
          //   }
          // } catch (NumberFormatException e){
          //    Log.d("TAG", "Неверный формат строки");
          // }
          // return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Element.java

```
package com.example.admin.wifiscanner;

class Element {
    private String title;
    private String security;
    private String level;

    Element(String title, String security, String level) {
        this.title = title;
        this.security = security;
        this.level = level;
    }

    String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    String getSecurity() {
        return security;
    }

     String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
}
```

Comment: А какая строка конкретно номер 67?

Answer (score 3):

Вы зачем-то парсите результаты сканирования как строки, и как только эта строка не в том формате, получаете ошибку.

Суть ошибки, вот здесь если вдруг в строке `item` меньше трех запятых

```
String[] vector_item = item.split(",");
```

То вот здесь получается выход за пределы массива

```
String item_level = vector_item[3];
```

Читайте данные прямо из полей `ScanResult` чтобы избежать подобных ошибок.